# font-awesome.css is linked, but doesn't make social network buttons appear

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

I have an issue about font-awesome.css. I linked it to my html file, but the social network buttons don't appear. I tried to link it from the web and from a local file. None of them seem to work.

Here is a living exemple of my code: http://www.bootply.com/NXt55uluJK
Here is the result i get : http://hpics.li/e9a2631

```
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <!--<link href="bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <link href="page_inscription.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <form class="form-signin" data-ember-action="2">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>

                <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary social-login-btn social-facebook" href="/auth/facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary social-login-btn social-twitter" href="/auth/twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </p>
                <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary social-login-btn social-linkedin" href="/auth/linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary social-login-btn social-google" href="/auth/google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                </p>

                <div class="btn-group social-login-more">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-block" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    More...
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu text-left " role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-sign"></i>   Tumblr</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i>   Github</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i>   Dropbox</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/auth/amazon"><span class="zocial-amazon"></span>   Amazon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="zocial-bitbucket"></span>   Bitbucket</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="zocial-evernote"></span>   Evernote</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="zocial-meetup"></span>   Meetup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-windows"></i>   Windows Live</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-weibo"></i>   Weibo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-foursquare"></i>   Foursquare</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-stackexchange"></i>   Stack Exchange</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trello"></i>   Trello</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="zocial-wordpress"></span>   Wordpress</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <br><br>



            </form>
        </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessaire à l'éxécution de Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
@import url("http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=brandico|entypo|openwebicons|zocial");

/* brandico */
[class*="brandico-"]:before {
  font-family: 'brandico', sans-serif;
}

/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}

/* openwebicons */
[class*="openwebicons-"]:before {
  font-family: 'OpenWeb Icons', sans-serif;
}

/* zocial */
[class*="zocial-"]:before {
  font-family: 'zocial', sans-serif;
}

.form-signin{
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.login-input {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.login-input-pass {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}


.signup-input {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.signup-input-confirm {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}



.create-account {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-center{
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: inherit;
}

.social-login-btn {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 250%;
  padding: 0;
}

.social-login-more {
  width: 45%;
}

.social-google {
  background-color: #da573b;
  border-color: #be5238;
}
.social-google:hover{
  background-color: #be5238;
  border-color: #9b4631;
}

.social-twitter {
  background-color: #1daee3;
  border-color: #3997ba;
}
.social-twitter:hover {
  background-color: #3997ba;
  border-color: #347b95;
}

.social-facebook {
  background-color: #4c699e;
  border-color: #47618d;
}
.social-facebook:hover {
  background-color: #47618d;
  border-color: #3c5173;
}

.social-linkedin {
  background-color: #4875B4;
  border-color: #466b99;
}
.social-linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #466b99;
  border-color: #3b5a7c;
}
```

Could you tell me why even if font-awesome.css is linked, social network buttons don't appear ?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: may be there is issue with font height

Comment: @sanoj lawrence i posted my code.

Comment: i can view font `facebook,twitter,google+,linked in`

Comment: there is problem in `page_inscription.css` insted post that

Comment: you might also want to use the fuller 4.2 version with the additional icons <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @Johnrednex add this to your css `.fa{font-size:50px;}` and check font appears or not

Comment: @sanoj lawrence I added your code line, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Johnrednex you have problem in this line `@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=brandico|entypo|openwebicons|zocial);` resolve this

Comment: @Johnrednex check my answer and try

Comment: @sanoj lawrence I added the quotes, but it still doesn't work

Comment: In fact  if i put `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">` or not it's the same thing. Here IS the issue.

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is an old post but I've just had this problem myself)

Your @import must be before ALL other content in your CSS file.

(credit: http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/#.VqYsKyqLTIU)

Answer (score 0):

you have unexpected token

### Replace

```
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=brandico|entypo|openwebicons|zocial);
```

### with

```
@import url("http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=brandico|entypo|openwebicons|zocial");
```

your url shoul be inside `Quotation` like above

### My outout

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i added the quotes. It still doesn't work.

Comment: In fact if i put `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">` or not it's the same thing. Here IS the issue.

Comment: i don't know what problem is because i get output what you want even added screen shot

Comment: I i said above, the script doesn't recognize the link. It doessn't work neither on windows, neither on ubuntu. I also tried on Firefox, Chrome, IE. I tried to add font-awesome with a local file too. But nothing is working :-/